# Why does $\frac{1}{4}x^2 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4x^2} = (\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2x})^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\frac{1}{4}x^2 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4x^2} = (\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2x})^2$

This is part of a solution to a more complex problem. Can someone explain what method was used here and how it works?

Here is the solution. The part I'm confused about it highlighted in red.

[image]

Comment: The method used is called ["Completing the Square"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square). It uses the formula $a^2+2ab+b^2=(a+b)^2$, which you can see is true by looking at [the following image](http://s22.postimg.org/xf3sgqzep/a_b_squared_scale_structure_in_square_system.gif).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+2xy$
So in this case :
$$
\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2x}\right)^2=\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{2x}\right)^2+2\frac{x}{2}\times\frac{1}{2x}=\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4x^2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

*(Edit: the first sentence here referred to an earlier version of the question, which was apparently mistyped).*

<s>It doesn't, except for a few special values of $x$. But</s>
$$\frac{1}{4}x^2 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4x^2} = \left(\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2x}\right)^2$$
as can be seen by unfolding the right-hand side with the usual rule $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$.

<s>Perhaps you've copied your source wrong, or there's a typo (or mistake!) there?</s>

Comment: I've posted a screen shot of what I'm confused about.

Comment: @Dunka: The rest of my answer still applies: Just unfold $(\frac12x+\frac1{2x})^2$ by the usual rule.

Comment: I see how it works when you reverse engineer it. But say I'm just at the the first step. How do I get to the end result?

Comment: @Dunka: By being clever and creative enough to notice that it will work. There's not really any general technique in use here; on the contrary it looks like the original curve has been very carefully selected such that $1+(y')^2$ would happen to be the square of something nice.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious. $$(\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2x})^2=(\frac{1}{2}x)^2+(\frac{1}{2x})^2+2(\frac{1}{2}x)(\frac{1}{2x})=\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{1}{4x^2}+\frac{1}{2}$$

$$(A+B)^2=A^2+B^2+2AB$$

Comment: Okay when you work out it in reverse it's always more simple. I understand they're equal, but how would I go from $RHS$ to the $LHS$ what technique do I use?

Comment: @Dunka When there is a $a^2+b^2$ in your statement, then simplify it as $(a+b)^2-2ab$, if you do this you see that the term $\frac{1}{2}$ will be absorbed in the squared part.

Comment: @Dunka: The technique of "recognizing, based on experience, that the expression happens to be of the form that would come out of the $(a+b)^2$ rule".

Comment: In that solution, you have two terms that are expressed as squared expressions

Comment: The method of making a statement in the form of a summation of a squared term plus other things is quite often in communication theory, when you are dealing with Gaussian channels.

Comment: AMIR, keep in mind the level of the student. I doubt that comment will help his or her understanding, and calling the answer "obvious" is demeaning.

Comment: @GFauxPas This answer completely addresses the OP's problem. Downvoting based on other factors is discouraged in SE model. So $+1$.